# Should you answer a question you think should be deleted/closed?

Tags: discussion

If you see a terrible formulated question which is hard to understand(for example bad english grammar or whatever) or a duplicate but you do know the answer to the question, should you still answer the bad question? Or just leave it be?

Comment: @gnat Well the question isn't the same because I'm not talking about an off-topic question although the answer helped me.

Comment: You're welcome to answer any question you'd like, __helping users is the primary goal.__

Comment: @LanceRoberts: No, **quality content is the primary goal**. Helping users out is a (most welcome) side effect.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, You have no site if you don't help users.  If you lose sight of that goal and try to just create a pure site, you will just have a nice looking site that is of no use to anyone. It's like any application you create; __It's always about the users and their needs.__

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Quality content attracts happy users, not the other way around.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, quality is great, and we should strive for that, but not before helping users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's salvageable, i.e. You can edit it and it won't be close worthy, it's best if you salvage it, then answer it.

If it is a sure duplicate or cannot be salvaged, it's best if you **didn't** answer it, and instead educate the OP on why his question is about to be closed/deleted.

Remember, our goal is quality, helping out other users is nice but it is a secondary goal. Flooding the site with answered duplicates doesn't help anyone, half-assed questions getting low quality answers (because you can't *really* answer a question the truly deserves being closed) doesn't help either.